# How to build Terraform provider for all platform?

Tags: go, terraform, provider

How do I build a Terraform provider like https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws for all platforms?

When I do `make build`, I only get one binary on Mac.

I would like to build for all the platforms Terraform usually supports.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile for a particular *single* other platform by setting the environment variables `GOOS` and `GOARCH` that the Go toolchain understands. For example, you can build for Windows on x86_64 by running this inside the provider's main package:

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go install
```

The process of building for *all* architectures that the provider team supports is unfortunately a build process maintained by each provider team and thus can vary between providers. However, a common pattern -- and one which is true for the AWS provider -- is to use [GoReleaser](https://goreleaser.com/) to build, tag, and publish releases across multiple platforms.

At the time of writing [the AWS provider's `.goreleaser.yml`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/19e8e245aa5642eec8c80bf2e2763f14e74e1808/.goreleaser.yml) specifies the matrix of supported OS and architecture combinations. Therefore if you install GoReleaser you can build distribution packages for the same set of targets using [`goreleaser build`](https://goreleaser.com/cmd/goreleaser_build/).

The same should be true for other providers where the team uses GoReleaser to manage their releases. Some providers might use other patterns, but at the time of writing GoReleaser is the technique recommended in the Terraform docs and so it's a pretty common choice.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass environment variables `GOOS` and `GOARCH` for the desired OS and architecture.

for ex: `GOOS=linux GOARCH=ppc64 go build` builds for linux ppc64 architecture.